# How does the corporate world of R&D view independant inventors?

Tags: licensing, research, grant

I have been working for 4 years as an independant inventor focused primarily on two patent families. Some are granted in those families.

However I am finding it very difficult to successfully license.

Lets say I were to go back to the world of corporate research - would my success in *inventing* be valued by the potential employers?

My initial assumption is that the answer is yes - however that there would be a discount applied to the "years of experience." Meaning that these 4 years are worth less than 4 years in a corporate research position.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: Answer edited based on revised question.**

How a corporation reacts to an independent research experience depends on how you present that experience. If it was full time work with a tangible deliverable then I expect a company will treat it like any other job. The point is to specify your actual demonstrable skills to the employer. If you have the requisite technical skills aligned with an open job posting than you have a good chance at getting hired. This point is important. R&D openings are specific to skills. If the company is looking for a material scientist, than your skills in some other field don't matter at all. Having a couple of granted patents should help as it indicates a record of innovation. However, the fact that may have written and processed the patents isn't relevant.

As for years of experience, if you spent four years doing relevant work, then it counts as four years of experience. Just focus on your technical accomplishments.

Comment: I have reworded my question as I seem to have made a mistake initially which became the focus of your answer.